# Customize back button for UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

[image]How to customize "Photo Album" back navigation button to "Photo"  in UIImagePickerController?

I have try my luck

Any idea how to customize the Photo Album back navigation button.

```
UIImagePickerController *albumPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
[albumPicker setDelegate:self];

[albumPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:albumPicker];

[popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,templatePhotoPlaceholderView.frame.size.height/2,templatePhotoPlaceholderView.frame.size.height) inView:templatePhotoPlaceholderView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
[popOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
[albumPicker release];
```

I want to customize the photo albums to Photo has shown in image and Saved Photos to Photo's 
How to do this I try it its not working for me

Comment: Any idea about the photo album button customized  in the UIImagePickercontroller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;

    // add done button to right side of nav bar
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photos"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                  target:self 
                                                                  action:@selector(saveImages:)];

    UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    [bar setHidden:NO];
    ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
    ipcNavBarTopItem.title = @"Photos";
    ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```

This is fixed the problem for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply this code to your controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn; // or rightBarButtonItem
[btn release];
```

Where self is a UIViewController - also remember you'll need to setup the action method for the selector.

Alternatively, you may be able to access the left/right button by drilling down into the controller's button view and then setting its title.

Answer (score 0):

after trying all  `[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIImagePickerController class], nil] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`
 solved my problem ,and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1710435?start=0&tstart=0) discussion help me learn about navigation in ImagePicker class